# How can I create a Python dict from a JSON object that contains escaped double quotes?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

In Python, if I receive this response from an API (via Python's "requests" module):

```
{"key": "<a href=\"www.foobar.com\""}
```

How can I convert it to a Python dict?

If I use json.dumps, for example:

```
request = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
request_text = request.text
json_output = json.loads(request_text)
```

I receive the following error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 19 (char 18)
```

Comment: Actually the sample response you have written is wrong it have an unnecessary `"` at the end. Remove that and then try with an actual response

Answer (score 0):

with reference to your response {"key": "<a href="www.foobar.com""},
I test with following method.

```
import json request_text = {"key": "<a href=\"www.foobar.com\""}
json_output = json.dumps(request_text)
a = json.loads(json_output)
print(a.get("key"))
```

expected result:
<a href="www.foobar.com"

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions:

1. Use `request.json()` instead of `request.text`
2. convert it into a raw string `r'{"key": "<a href=\"www.foobar.com\""}'`, using any unicode encoding methods.